# Use of uninitialized value in string eq. left or right?

Tags: perl, initialization

I am clearing up some code and I see in our server logs that the perl error is ...

```
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at .....
```

Looking at the code the line looks like this....

```
if ($level1 eq $level2) {
```

OK fair enough. I suppose my question is this. Is it $level1 or $level2 that's the problem?

I wrote a quick test to try to replicate it locally and it looks like this....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
my $a;
my $b;

if ($a eq $b){
    print "....";
}
```

And I get a much more informative error.

```
Use of uninitialized value $a in string eq at ./warntest.cgi line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $b in string eq at ./warntest.cgi line 7.
```

This is seemingly inconsistent behavior. Does anyone have a clue?
Janie

Comment: Why don't you give the contents of the line of the first error?  Without seeing anything, my guess would be you're comparing the result of a function call or a hash/array value lookup.  That is, it's not a simple undefined, named scalar.

Comment: you should **use diagnostics** pragma if you are getting a warning which you don't understand

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The indication of which variable was undef was added to the warning (where easily possible) in perl 5.10 (to much cheering).  Your server is likely using an older perl.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perl5100delta.pod#New_or_Changed_Diagnostics

Comment: LOL, now I realise the question is about the difference in the warning message.

Comment: BAM! That's it! ysth, you have enlightened me once again! JW